# Discontinuous Galerkin FEM : Control points are mid-points of edges instead of nodes

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am thinking to use discontinuous galerkin FEM (DGFEM) method to estimate discontinuous displacement field $u: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ at the crack surface of a material.

The domain is discretized with triangles. I can think two ways to define control points where we evaluate displacement fields

1. Control points are defined on vertices/nodes of a triangle (probably knows as nodal DGFEM in the literature)
2. Control points are defined on mid-points of the edges. (like in Crouzeix–Raviart elements)

I could not find a reference where second method has been employed to model DGFEM.

Will there be something wrong mathematically if we define control points on mid-points of edges to model DGEM?

Comment: What do you mean by "second method " ?  If you mean second order method, then this is just linear finite volume methods.